# How To Find All Images in BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to have a list of all our used images, but there is no way I could clone our hundreds of BitBucket repositories to manually search for them.

I hoped there was a chance to use the search to find all of them. [The documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/search-873876782.html) has a couple of ideas, none of which work:

- `ext:png` returns an empty result
- `path:*.png` returns all files that contain "path" and "png"

It seems the search only handles text files. Or maybe the searches need the second parameter. Or probably both.

I checked the "Code search considerations" to see if something interesting would pop up, but I there is not:

- there are images on the master
- the files are below 320KB
- they only have one extension
- I have permissions to view the repositories

Nothing about the fact that this is a text search only (even though the key words `ext` and `path` suggest something different).

Is there a way to get a list of all the images of our git repositories?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find all picture in all my repo with this query. By clicking on the magnifying glass at the left in bitbucket overview

[image]

Not really that is the right way...

Comment: Weird, I have the magnifying glass on the top right, not left. And this query doesn't work either. =(